# Getting Error ORA-01017 invalid username/password after changing computer name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

recently I had to change my computer name and now I am getting this error whenever I try to connect to my local oracle 11g express edition database via OracelSQL Developer.

I have already changed my listener and

tnsnames(D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN) to reflect the my

computer's new name but I am still getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is SQL Developer using a TNS entry in the first place? Or is it still trying to connect to the old host name, in the connect settings? Of course that would only get this error if the name (or IP) is now pointing to a different server with a database, which is maybe unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

You must be using operating system authentication `OPS$` prefixed username. Connect with `sys` or `system` and fix your DB user account. Search for `OPS$` user in Oracle documentation for more details.

Comment: I have checked and I don't have any of the boxes checked(os authentication, kerberos authentication and proxy authentication) none of these are checked before and I could connect to the DB.